# Wheel Collider (rpm)

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

Hi All if this is the right question in the right place please help me. As I understand motor torque in Wheel Collider is how much force is applied to the wheel but I don't understand why rpm depends on torque. For example, if I have engine rpm 2000 and gear ratio 4 and final drive 3 it will cause the tire to rotate at 2000/4/3 rpm if I have 150 even 2000 nm force from engine. I want to understand Wheel Collider rpm depends on what? If this is not the right question can you redirect me? P.S. I don't want to someone to write code. I just want to understand what is really going on on wheel colliders. I watched documentation in Unity site but there is not enough information about how wheel collider rpm calculated.

Comment: I don't understand why I get undervoted lol :D

Comment: I am now investigating more. Later I will post an answer about wheel curve values mass  and normal configuration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After many hours of investigation, I find that wheel collider's rpm depends on torque it's mass and (in this case Forward only direction) Forward Friction properties(Extremum slip and etc.).If you have a problem with high rotation or low rotation in rpm property try to change values of these properties and of course understand whats going on. Sorry for bothering you.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-WheelCollider.html?_ga=2.133155214.1204857265.1581511341-270469021.1544164377